# how to solve the rational exp integral?

Tags: integration

I want to solve this rational exp function but i don't know how!

$$\int_{\nu}^{\infty} \frac{ax}{bx+c} \exp\{-\alpha x-\frac{\beta}{x}\}$$

Comment: I would try to integrate on complex numbers contour closed at infinity.

Comment: you mean that you want a closed-form expression for this integral? that is not likely to exist.

Comment: yes,  A closed-form

Comment: so it must be solve with numerical methods ?

Answer (score 2):

Since $\nu$ is arbitrary, what you need is an antiderivative. 
But, assuming $a,b,c \ne 0$, the antiderivative is non-elementary.

**Proof:**  By a theorem of Liouville, the only case where $r(x) \exp(p(x))$ (where $r(x)$ and $p(x)$ are rational functions, $p$ non-constant) has an elementary antiderivative is where that antiderivative is of the form $R(x) \exp(p(x))$ with $R(x)$ rational.
This would then satisfy the differential equation
$$   R'(x) + p'(x) R(x) = r(x)$$

In your case, assuming $a,b,c \ne 0$, $r(x) = ax/(bx+c)$ has a pole of order $1$ at $x = -c/b$, which is not a singularity of $p'(x)$.  If $R(x)$ had a pole of order $1$, $R'(x)$ would have a pole of order $2$.  So there is no such rational function $R$.

Comment: what about for this integral (a closed-form expression)

Comment: $\int_v^{\infty} \exp\{−αx−βx\} dx$